# FFMPEG ID3 Metadata for FLAC Files?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

I'm interested in converting an mp3 I made to FLAC using ID3 tags.

I'm having 2 issues:

**1) The Album Art from the old MP3's Doesn't Copy Over**

and

**2) I don't know how to encode an old MP3 with new album art**

So far I have: `ffmpeg -i IN.mp3 -compression_level 6 OUT.flac` which copies over *most* of the metadata (but not the album art unfortunatly).

How would I copy over old album art, and set new album art/metadata using ID3 tags using FFMPEG?

Comment: There is absolutely no point whatsoever in converting mp3 to flac. All you will gain is a bigger file.

Comment: I suppose that's true. I guess it generalizes to other file formats as well though, and would be generally useful for adding metadata using ID3 tags.

Comment: Your worked for me. Can't really comment further without seeing the complete log.